# Standartized residuals of generalized nonlinear least square model (gnls) with R 'by Hand'

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, autocorrelation, residuals, standardization

I want to fit a nonlinear model by using generalized least squares regression with the function `gnls` of the package `nlme` of R. Thereby, the residuals of the fit show heteroscedasticity and autocorrelation, why I want to include, e.g., the `varPower()` variance structure and the `corAR1()` correlation structure in the regression.

For model diagnostics I would like to plot the fitted values against the standardized residuals. As far as I see, there is no standard routine available for the `gnls` function to produce this plot or to calculate the standardized residuals automatically. This is why I try to do it manually.

In contrast, for the `gls` function, the plot fitted values against standardized residuals is available. Because of this I produced an example with the `gls` function and try to calculate the standardized residuals manually, which actually doesn't work.

For calculating the standardized residuals I used the following method which works for linear models, but not for the `gls` with the `varPower()` variance structure.

\begin{align}
r_i    &= \frac{e_i}{\sqrt{MSE(1-h_{ii})}}  \\[5pt]
h_{ii} &= \frac{1}{n} + \frac{(x_i - \bar x)^2}{SS_x}
\end{align}

Here is an example dataset with heteroscedasticity and a fitted `gls`:

```
x_gls <- runif(100)
y_gls <- 1 - 2*x_gls + .3*x_gls*rnorm(100)
fit_gls1 = gls(y_gls~x_gls)
plot(x_gls, y_gls)
abline(fit_gls1$coefficients)
```

[image: example data with clear heteroscedasticity]

I get the diagnostics plot with fitted values against standardized residuals by:

```
plot(fit_gls1)
```

[image: standardized residuals vs. fitted values (heteroscedasticity)]

a similar plot I get by manually calculating the standardized residuals

```
resid_gls1    = fit_gls1$residuals
mse_gls1      = fit_gls1$sigma**2
n_gls1        = length(x_gls)
leverage_gls1 = 1/n*(x_gls-mean(x_gls))**2/(sum(x_gls-mean(x_gls)**2))
standres_gls1 = resid_gls1/(sqrt(mse_gls1*(1-leverage_gls1))
plot(fit_gls1$fitted, standres_gls1)
```

[image: manually calculated standardized residuals]

If I now use the `varPower()` variance structure for `gls` model, I am not able to reproduce the standardized residuals:

```
fit_gls2 = gls(y_gls~x_gls, weights=varPower(form=~x_gls))
plot(fit_gls2)
```

[image: standardized residuals with the varPower() variance structure]

Standardized residuals calculated manually with the same procedure like before look quite different:

```
resid_gls2    = fit_gls2$residuals
mse_gls2      = fit_gls2$sigma**2
n_gls2        = length(x_gls)
leverage_gls2 = 1/n*(x_gls-mean(x_gls))**2/(sum(x_gls-mean(x_gls)**2))
standres_gls2 = resid_gls2/(sqrt(mse_gls2*(1-leverage_gls2)))
plot(fit_gls2$fitted, standres_gls2)
```

[image: manually calculated standardized residuals look quite different]

So how can I calculate the standardized residuals manually? I need to calculate them for a `gnls` model, where there exist no automated diagnostic plots (at least as far as I know...). I think I need to incorporate the `varPower()` variance structure, but how? And what about if I also want to incorporate a `corAR1()` correlation structure?

Comment: does anybody have any idea?

Comment: You have to include the fitted values of varPower in the residual calculation. I believe there is no standard way to "correct" for a fitted AR1 - it seems obvious that you could calculate the expected correlogram under the fitted AR1 and compare this to your actual correlogram, but not sure if that's the best way to do this.